# Swagger doc for api response (type List)

Tags: java, swagger

I am using swagger to generate the documentation of my REST API. However I am having problems specifying the responses of some API calls.

This is my code:

```
@GET
@Path("/self/activities")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Get all activities created by this user",
            notes = "Returns the list that the authenticated user   (JWT) has created",
            response = Activity.class,
            responseContainer = "List")
@ApiResponses(value = {
      @ApiResponse(code = 400, response = ErrorResponse.Error.class, responseContainer = "List", message = "There was something wrong in the request and therefore could not be processed (headers, json syntax/content)"),
      @ApiResponse(code = 500, response = ErrorResponse.Error.class, responseContainer = "List", message = "Unknown Internal server error")})
public void getActivities(...){...}
```

And this is the doc that it generates:

```
"responses" : {
      "200" : {
        "description" : "successful operation",
        "schema" : {
          "type" : "array",
          "items" : {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/Activity"
          }
        }
      },
      "400" : {
        "description" : "There was something wrong in the request and therefore could not be processed (headers, json syntax/content)",
        "schema" : {
          "$ref" : "#/definitions/Error"
        }
      },
      "500" : {
        "description" : "Unknown Internal server error",
        "schema" : {
          "$ref" : "#/definitions/Error"
        }
      }
    }
```

And I do not understand why the error responses are not of type 'Array' like the 200 Response. What I want is that all the responses have the same format as the 200 responses (array with items):

```
 "500" : {
        "description" : "Uknown interval server error",
        "schema" : {
          "type" : "array",
          "items" : {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/Error"
          }
        }
      }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which version of swagger-core do you use here?

Answer (score 11):

```
@ApiResponse(code = 400, response = ErrorResponse.Error.class, responseContainer = "List", message = "There was something wrong in the request and therefore could not be processed (headers, json syntax/content)"),
  @ApiResponse(code = 500, response = ErrorResponse.Error.class, responseContainer = "List", message = "Unknown Internal server error")})
```

400 and 500 errors response will return an ErrorResponse. Not an array.

Comment: But it should be an array because I am specifying `responseContainer = "List"`. And I am pretty sure that this is the way to do it, because If I put the 200 response inside the '@ApiResponses' in this format it works.